# How to delete particular message between two user from ejabberd using XMPPFramework?

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, xmppframework, ejabberd-module

I am trying to delete the message from ejabberd but getting the error from it.

`<iq xmlns="jabber:client" to="my id" from="other user id" type="error" id="8A056958-DE72-4234-8440-928E8D650948"><remove xmlns="urn:xmpp:archive" with="other user id" start="2018-08-30T10:40:00Z"/><error code="503" type="cancel"><service-unavailable xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/><text xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas">No module is handling this query</text></error></iq>`

Please help.

Comment: Where did you read that this is possible? How did you attempt to do it?

Comment: Please check the link:
https://xmpp.org/extensions/attic/xep-0136-1.0.html

7.3 Removing a Collection
Example 43. Removing a single collection

Answer (score 0):

From what I see here https://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/protocols/

Ejabberd does not support old Message Archiving XEP-0136, instead it supports XEP-0313 Message Archive Management.

The following XEP can be used to implement message deletion on sender & recipient http://legastero.github.io/customxeps/extensions/message-delete.html

But I do not know how to delete messages from XEP-0313 Message Archive Management - looks like it's not possible with ejabberd and the XEP itself. I do not see any message id stored in DB https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/master/src/mod_mam_sql.erl#L110

The only one idea I have is to store text messages along with delete statuses in archive. And then, when retrieve history, apply these delete signals to messages

Comment: Can you please provide a GitHub link to an example on how to delete from history as you mentioned in the last paragraph in your answer? I’m also stuck in this problem where I require deletion of user specific messages in the ejabberd MAM from a client.

Comment: @JohnYepthomi sorry, I have not done it by myself and do not know any of the examples. This is just my understanding how it should work. But, generally speaking, just store delete-messages in a same way as normal messages. Then when retrieve, apply delete-messages on top of normal messages